# Could not load file or assembly System, Version 2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, gac

I have a .NET application that currently builds and runs fine in a development environment but running the application on another machine is throwing this error.

The machine I am trying to run this on is running Windows Server 2012 which has .NET 4.5 baked into it. The error appears to be a .NET error however the GAC is showing the System Version 2.0.0.0 assembly installed. Also nothing is being written to Event Viewer on the application crash.

Any help or any idea of where to begin looking is appreciated.

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: Could you share the output of `gacutil  -l | find "System, Version=2.0.0.0"` from the developer command prompt?  Is it possible the PublicKeyToken is off?  Otherwise, it sounds like you're missing some .NET 3.5 feature on the Windows 2012 server...

Comment: Dan is correct, installing .NET 3.5 fixed the issue. I must have some dependency that was referencing a 3.5 library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dan from above was correct, installing .NET 3.5 on the server fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

This link may possibly explain the error:

[Make sure your .NET framework is patched.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903657/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-version-2-0-5-0-in-net-4-mvc-4-applicat)

It seems that the best explanation is that the server needs patched--but it could be the development machine as well.