# .NET 4.6.1 causes .NET 4 applications to not find a connection string in the application config file

Tags: .net

.NET v4.6.1 framework is rolling out across the domain where I work and is breaking .NET v4 applications deployed by ClickOnce.  In particular the error message is "No connection string named <> could be found in the application config file.

Up to now my work around has been to uninstall v4.6.1, the install v4.  About 50% of the time this resolves the problem with the v4 program.  The other 50% of the time when the v4 program is launched another error is thrown which is "Could not load file or assembly System, Version=2.0.5.0 in .NET 4 MVC 4 application" This was solved using the suggestion from this page [ [Could not load file or assembly System, Version=2.0.5.0 in .NET 4 MVC 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903657/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-version-2-0-5-0-in-net-4-mvc-4-applicat) ] to install MS KB2468871 [ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2468871 ].

Now I have a computer that requires 4.6.1 so I can no longer solve this problem by correcting the symptom of removing 4.6.1.  Would my .NET v4 application be using v4.6.1 at runtime, and if so, is there a change in the way the application config file is searched for in v4.6.1 for ClickOnce programs?

UPDATE - this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2.aspx) states that when .NET 4.5 is installed, all .NET 4 programs will run under v4.5+ and that v4.0 and v4.5+ cannot coexist.  So my v4.0 program is being hosted by v.4.6.1.  Now I need to find out how the application configuration file has changed in v4.6.1 versus v4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688) explains how to use a different app.config file at run-time.  Implementing the class in my program and making a call to its Change() method appears to have solved the problem.  Still, I would like to know where v4.6.1 is looking for the app.config, or the .dll.config file.