# Could not load file or assembly System, Version=2.0.5.0 due to the referenced assembly targeting .Net Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I have a project which is running on .Net framework 4.5. But it has a reference to a dll which is targeting the .Net framework 3.5 in which it has reference to mscorlib and system dlls. While running the code I am getting exception as Could not load file or assembly System, Version=2.0.5.0.

I have seen the below article which is similar to my problem.

[Could not load file or assembly System, Version=2.0.5.0 in .NET 4 MVC 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903657/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-version-2-0-5-0-in-net-4-mvc-4-applicat)

But the patch whichever mentioned ((KB2468871)) doesn't working for me. When I try to install it's showing the message as 
"KB2468871v2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer."

I don't have control on the referenced assembly to change the framework.

So Can anybody please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error "KB2468871v2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer." come mostly from low disk space, make sure you have at least 2 GB free disk space before running the update, make sure you reject all removable devices also.
If it does not work, try going into Control Panel --> "Uninstall a program" and click on "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile", then select "Repair .NET Framework 4 Client Profile"

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile"   in control Panel.

Comment: In fact, it's Control panel --> Uninstall a program. Try to repair "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 _anything_" if you don't find "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile"

Comment: All I can see 4.5 related things. I am working with vs2013. Current project framework is 4.5 and one of the dll has a reference to .Net 3.5

Comment: Yes, sorry i meant 4.5.

Comment: It's not solved the problem. Still I am getting the same

Comment: Try to install the update now, please check that you have 2 GB free disk space in C: disk

Comment: No luck. still same issue with the patch also

Comment: It means you no longer have this error "KB2468871v2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer." ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111175/discussion-between-chandra-mohan-and-zakariaa-b).